# Google account and installed apps disappeared after an unexpected restart

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, google-account, samsung-galaxy-note-3, accounts

I have a Note 3 N9005, Lollipop installed on it. My phone just restarted in my pocket, by my clothes "pressing" power and home button (why does that restarts the phone?).

After it restarted various apps started crashing (contacts storage, settings, internet, android.process.media, Gallery, Key chain) and my installed apps disappeared, so when i want to start them it says app is not installed.

Tried starting Play Store but it insta-closes and does nothing. Neither my other google apps (calendar, keep). So I tried to logout from my Google account, but I can't find it on my list. Account list is empty, and when I tap add account can't find Google.

Here is what I tried:

- soft restart
- battery remove
- clearing Google Play cache
- removing Google Play updates
- clearing every Google app's cache

What's happening to the phone? I don't want a factory reset, but it seems there's no other way.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: wat][image: IMG: wat]

Update:
two new unsucessful tries:

- I rooted the device to try and delete accounts.xml and accounts.db, both came out as a dead end
- Wiped cache partition in recovery

Also I tried to factory reset from the Settings menu and I couldn't... safe to say this is hopeless, last try of mine will be factory reset from the recovery menu.

Comment: if you did a factory reset and cleaned cache and dalvik cache, one time init setup should initialize at start and allow you to setup a google account.

Comment: As your phone is rooted now, backup your apps and data using Titanium Backup Tools and factory reset the phone..

Comment: It takes some time for the updates of google play services and other apps to complete. During this update, you receive(even for google play store) the app is not installed. You should be connected to WiFi, not a mobile network.